# uWSGI on ubuntu 18 suddenly fails when --never-swap specified

Tags: ubuntu, uwsgi

I use uWSGI on ubuntu 18 (18.04.5 LTS). Very recently this stopped working - I'd get this error on startup:

`Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from MemoryErrors while normalizing exceptions.`

Nothing had changed my side but the server was set to auto-upgrade. Running uwsgi as root worked, but as www-data (which is how I run it normally) failed.

After some trial and error it turned out that the `--never-swap` option was causing this - certainly when I removed that, it worked again.

So I can live with removing `--never-swap`, but I'd love to know why this happened. Is some new security feature preventing non-root users locking memory pages - that's what the doc says this option does - [uWSGI doc here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#never-swap).

Answer (score 0):

An unprivileged process needs the CAP_IPC_LOCK capability in order to lock memory pages. Most likely someone (you or another admin) set this capability manually, and then it was of course gone when a recent update was installed.

Comment: Thanks - interesting but I don't think that's relevant to me - I configured the server and have never made any change to that. Unless a default changed?